# Transaction pool error: Too low priority (0 > 0)

Tags: extrinsic, nonce, transaction-pool, tx-pool

im trying to submit multiple unsigned extrinsics to the transaction pool but an Error is returned which says:

> Transaction pool error: Too low priority (0 > 0)

i thought this might be related to the nonce but how come an unsigned extrinsic have a nonce if its not associated with an account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, and it was when implementing the validate_unsigned trait, I needed to make each extrinsic unique in the tags, and I did it by encoding the whole call, like this:

```rust
ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("MyPallet")
    .and_provides(call.encode())
    .build()
```